# Achieve creativity in natural language generation?

Tags: nlp, nlg

Is it possible for an approach based on supervised learning from a fixed dataset to achieve creativity in NLG?

Answer (score 0):

The question forces you to define "achieve creativity".  I would think if a parrot were to string together words and phrases, in new ways, all day long I wouldn't call it creative till it reached an objective, or induced a feeling.  If "Polly wanna cracker" was in the training set then I wouldn't call it creative to see the parrot try that one.  I don't believe supervised learning would do it.  You can use data to train models like Bert and word2vec about probabilities of words being used in a situation and topic modeling to stay on topic and it can put together in less probable ways so it seems new and novel.  Is that creativity?